# Conflitos no MS-Access

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Tenho uma tabela em um banco de dados access com os seguintes campos:

```
DATA       | SALA | AULA1 | AULA2 | AULA3 | AULA4 | DOCENTE | TURNO
----------------------------------------------------------------------
02/02/2015 | S1   | 1     | 1     | 0     | 0     | JOÃO    | MATUTINO
----------------------------------------------------------------------
02/02/2015 | S1   | 0     | 0     | 1     | 1     | JORGE   | MATUTINO    
----------------------------------------------------------------------
02/02/2015 | S1   | 1     | 1     | 0     | 0     | JOSÉ    | MATUTINO
----------------------------------------------------------------------    
02/02/2015 | S2   | 1     | 1     | 1     | 0     | MARIA   | MATUTINO
```

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta que retornasse as aulas em conflito no dia levando em consideração o dia e a sala utilizada.

Ex:
Dia 02/02/2015 a sala 01 está sendo utilizada pela turma nos dois primeiros horários de aula e nos dois finais. Notem que no mesmo dia 2 (3ª linha) existe conflito entre a 3ª e a 1ª linha (no campo aula 1 e 2). Gostaria de uma formatar uma consulta que informe estes dois conflitos.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Perdão pelo formato da tabela...não consegui configurar de jeito nenhum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partindo do principio que sua tabela possui um identificador e utilizando o `EXISTS`, facilita a consulta:

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM suatabela t1
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT t2.id 
              FROM suatabela t2 
              WHERE t1.ID <> t2.ID 
                AND t1.DATA = t2.DATA 
                AND t1.SALA = t2.SALA
                AND (t1.AULA1 = 1 AND t2.AULA1 = 1)
                     OR (t1.AULA2 = 1 AND t2.AULA2 = 1)
                     OR (t1.AULA3 = 1 AND t2.AULA3 = 1)
                     OR (t1.AULA4 = 1 AND t2.AULA4 = 1))
             )
```

```
t1.ID <> t2.ID
```

Essa é a parte mais importante do SELECT.

Deve ter algum jeito mais fácil, mas to sem criatividade agora.

`suatabela`: essa tabela que você mostrou as informações.

Comment: Fera, mas esse comando **Inner Join** não é para juntar informações de mais de uma tabela?

No meu caso é apenas uma tabela

Comment: @FilipeS.Martins Por isso mesmo, eu junto a própria tabela 2x pra encontrar as coincidências.

Comment: Entendi, muito bom cara, nem imaginava que dava pra fazer isso. Notei que na saída da consulta apareceram os campos **T1.(rotulodocampo)** e **T2.(rotulodocampo)** de todos os campos que inseri na consulta. Tem como simplificar isto?

Comment: @FilipeS.Martins Você quer pegar o que?

Comment: DATA       | SALA | AULA1 | AULA2 | AULA3 | AULA4 | DOCENTE | TURNO

basicamente as informações que estão na tabela mesmo.

Muito obrigado pela ajuda Maicon Carraro

Comment: @FilipeS.Martins No caso tu tem conflito da linha 1 e 3, qual docente tu vai mostrar? os 2?

Comment: Exato, mostra na verdade todas as linhas que tem conflito. É como se fosse mostrar as linhas que estão duplicadas nos campos (data e sala e(aula1 ou aula2 ou aula3 ou aula4)

Comment: Nesse caso acho melhor outra solução, utilizando `EXISTS`, só pra confirmar tu tem id nessa tabela?

Comment: Sim, tenho um campo codigo com numeração automatica

Comment: @FilipeS.Martins Alterei a resposta com a nova solução, da uma testada

Comment: Nessa última que você mandou acabou dando um erro de sintaxe na expressão EXISTS...

Comment: @FilipeS.Martins Cola o erro inteiro aqui

Comment: Erro de sintaxe na expressão de consulta 

'EXISTS (
              SELECT t2.ID 
              FROM TblHorario t2 ON t1.ID <> t2.ID AND t1.DATA = t2.DATA AND t1.SALA = t2.SALA
              WHERE (t1.AULA1 = 1 AND t2.AULA1 = 1)
                 OR (t1.AULA2 = 1 AND t2.AULA2 = 1)

Comment: Falta fechar mais um parênteses

Comment: Fechei  mas o erro persiste. Nao será alguma vírgula que ficou faltando?

Comment: @FilipeS.Martins Perdao, eu tinha esquecido um `ON` dentro do exists, arrumei na resposta da uma conferida

Comment: Top Maicon, acho que agora funcionou blz! Vou fazer mais testes....Valeu pela força.

Comment: Qualquer coisa só pingar meu nome novamente :)